# Math formula to convert NAD83 State Plane to NAD83 UTM (ultimate goal is to convert to WGS84 Lat/Lng)

Tags: t-sql, gis, transformation

**My ultimate goal**:

Write a **TSQL function to convert NAD83 State Plane** (specifically ESRI Projection 102738 http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102738/) **to WGS84 Lat/Lng** so I can, in near real-time, plot the original coordinates on a Google Map.

**I do not want to use an external library such as Proj4 or GDAL because I want to avoid external, non-sql dependencies** that I am afraid won't get reinstalled by future admins when our database servers are upgraded.

1. I found javascript code (http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html) to convert NAD83 UTM to WGS84 Lat/Long (see below). I have ported/converted this to SQL successfully.
2. I don't know how to find the math to write a function that can convert NAD83 State Plane coordinates to NAD 83 UTM (so I can then use my existing function to convert UTM to Lat/Lng)

TSQL I've ported from JS to convert NAD83 UTM to WGS84:

```
/*Adapted from: http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html*/

-----------------------------------------
--USER INPUTS
DECLARE @Operation VARCHAR(50) = 'FromUTMToGeo'
DECLARE @Input_X_or_Lat FLOAT = 686847.2227879118 
DECLARE @Input_Y_or_Lng FLOAT = 3653063.504053675
DECLARE @Input_Geog_Zone INT = 14
DECLARE @Input_Geog_Hemi VARCHAR(1) = 'N'

------------------------------------------
--CONSTANTS
DECLARE @gbl_pi FLOAT = 3.14159265358979
DECLARE @gbl_sm_a FLOAT = 6378137.0;
DECLARE @gbl_sm_b FLOAT = 6356752.314;
DECLARE @gbl_sm_EccSquared FLOAT = 6.69437999013e-03;
DECLARE @gbl_UTMScaleFactor FLOAT = 0.9996;

--RadToDeg(rad): (rad / pi * 180.0)
--DegToRad(deg): (deg / 180.0 * pi)

------------------------------------------
IF @Operation = 'FromUTMToGeo'
    BEGIN   
    ----------------------------------
        DECLARE @x float = 0
        DECLARE @y float = 0
        DECLARE @southhemi bit = 0
        IF @Input_Geog_Hemi = 'S' SET @southhemi = 1        

        ----------------------------------
        --X and Y
        SET @x = (@Input_X_or_Lat - 500000.0)
        SET @x = @x / @gbl_UTMScaleFactor

        IF @southhemi = 1 BEGIN SET @y = (@Input_Y_or_Lng - 10000000.0) END
        SET @y = @Input_Y_or_Lng / @gbl_UTMScaleFactor


        ----------------------------------
        --cmeridian
        --  DegToRad (-183.0 + (zone * 6.0));
        DECLARE @cmeridian FLOAT = (-183.0 + (@Input_Geog_Zone * 6.0)) / 180 * @gbl_pi
        DECLARE @lambda0 FLOAT = @cmeridian

        ----------------------------------
        --Calculate Latitude and Longtitude
        DECLARE @phif FLOAT
        DECLARE @Nf FLOAT 
        DECLARE @Nfpow FLOAT 
        DECLARE @nuf2 FLOAT 
        DECLARE @ep2 FLOAT 
        DECLARE @tf FLOAT 
        DECLARE @tf2 FLOAT 
        DECLARE @tf4 FLOAT 
        DECLARE @cf FLOAT

        DECLARE @x1frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x2frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x3frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x4frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x5frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x6frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x7frac FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x8frac FLOAT
        DECLARE @x2poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x3poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x4poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x5poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x6poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x7poly FLOAT 
        DECLARE @x8poly FLOAT

        DECLARE @Lat_AsRad FLOAT
        DECLARE @Lng_AsRad FLOAT  
        DECLARE @Latitude FLOAT
        DECLARE @Longitude FLOAT        

        -------------------------------------------------------------
        /* Get the value of phif, the footpoint latitude. */
        DECLARE @y_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @alpha_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @beta_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @gamma_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @delta_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @epsilon_ FLOAT
        DECLARE @n FLOAT
        DECLARE @FootpointLatitude FLOAT

        /* Precalculate n (Eq. 10.18) */
        SET @n = (@gbl_sm_a - @gbl_sm_b) / (@gbl_sm_a + @gbl_sm_b);

        /* Precalculate alpha_ (Eq. 10.22) */
        /* (Same as alpha in Eq. 10.17) */
        SET @alpha_ = ((@gbl_sm_a + @gbl_sm_b) / 2.0) * (1 + (POWER(@n, 2.0) / 4) + (POWER(@n, 4.0) / 64));

        /* Precalculate y_ (Eq. 10.23) */
        SET @y_ = @y / @alpha_;

        /* Precalculate beta_ (Eq. 10.22) */
        SET @beta_ = (3.0 * @n / 2.0) + (-27.0 * POWER(@n, 3.0) / 32.0) + (269.0 * POWER(@n, 5.0) / 512.0);

        /* Precalculate gamma_ (Eq. 10.22) */
        SET @gamma_ = (21.0 * POWER(@n, 2.0) / 16.0) + (-55.0 * POWER(@n, 4.0) / 32.0);

        /* Precalculate delta_ (Eq. 10.22) */
        SET @delta_ = (151.0 * POWER(@n, 3.0) / 96.0) + (-417.0 * POWER(@n, 5.0) / 128.0);

        /* Precalculate epsilon_ (Eq. 10.22) */
        SET @epsilon_ = (1097.0 * POWER(@n, 4.0) / 512.0);

        /* Now calculate the sum of the series (Eq. 10.21) */
        SET @FootpointLatitude = @y_ + (@beta_ * SIN(2.0 * @y_))
            + (@gamma_ * SIN(4.0 * @y_))
            + (@delta_ * SIN(6.0 * @y_))
            + (@epsilon_ * SIN(8.0 * @y_));

        SET @phif = @FootpointLatitude
        -------------------------------------------------------------   

        /* Precalculate ep2 */
        SET @ep2 = (POWER(@gbl_sm_a, 2.0) -POWER(@gbl_sm_b, 2.0)) / POWER(@gbl_sm_b, 2.0);

        /* Precalculate cos (phif) */
        SET @cf = COS(@phif);

        /* Precalculate nuf2 */
        SET @nuf2 = @ep2 * POWER(@cf, 2.0);

        /* Precalculate Nf and initialize Nfpow */
        SET @Nf = POWER(@gbl_sm_a, 2.0) / (@gbl_sm_b * SQRT(1 + @nuf2));
        SET @Nfpow = @Nf;

        /* Precalculate tf */
        SET @tf = TAN(@phif);
        SET @tf2 = @tf * @tf;
        SET @tf4 = @tf2 * @tf2;

        /* Precalculate fractional coefficients for x**n in the equations
           below to simplify the expressions for latitude and longitude. */
        SET @x1frac = 1.0 / (@Nfpow * @cf);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**2) */
        SET @x2frac = @tf / (2.0 * @Nfpow);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**3) */
        SET @x3frac = 1.0 / (6.0 * @Nfpow * @cf);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**4) */
        SET @x4frac = @tf / (24.0 * @Nfpow);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**5) */
        SET @x5frac = 1.0 / (120.0 * @Nfpow * @cf);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**6) */
        SET @x6frac = @tf / (720.0 * @Nfpow);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**7) */
        SET @x7frac = 1.0 / (5040.0 * @Nfpow * @cf);

        SET @Nfpow *= @Nf;   /* now equals Nf**8) */
        SET @x8frac = @tf / (40320.0 * @Nfpow);

        /* Precalculate polynomial coefficients for x**n.
           -- x**1 does not have a polynomial coefficient. */
        SET @x2poly = -1.0 - @nuf2;

        SET @x3poly = -1.0 - 2 * @tf2 - @nuf2;

        SET @x4poly = 5.0 + 3.0 * @tf2 + 6.0 * @nuf2 - 6.0 * @tf2 * @nuf2 - 3.0 * (@nuf2 *@nuf2) - 9.0 * @tf2 * (@nuf2 * @nuf2);

        SET @x5poly = 5.0 + 28.0 * @tf2 + 24.0 * @tf4 + 6.0 * @nuf2 + 8.0 * @tf2 * @nuf2;

        SET @x6poly = -61.0 - 90.0 * @tf2 - 45.0 * @tf4 - 107.0 * @nuf2 + 162.0 * @tf2 * @nuf2;

        SET @x7poly = -61.0 - 662.0 * @tf2 - 1320.0 * @tf4 - 720.0 * (@tf4 * @tf2);

        SET @x8poly = 1385.0 + 3633.0 * @tf2 + 4095.0 * @tf4 + 1575 * (@tf4 * @tf2);

        /* Calculate latitude */
        SET @Lat_AsRad = @phif + @x2frac * @x2poly * (@x * @x)
            + @x4frac * @x4poly * POWER(@x, 4.0)
            + @x6frac * @x6poly * POWER(@x, 6.0)
            + @x8frac * @x8poly * POWER(@x, 8.0);
        --Radians to Degrees
        SET @Latitude =  (@Lat_AsRad / @gbl_pi * 180.0) 

        /* Calculate longitude */
        SET @Lng_AsRad = @lambda0 + @x1frac * @x
            + @x3frac * @x3poly * POWER(@x, 3.0)
            + @x5frac * @x5poly * POWER(@x, 5.0)
            + @x7frac * @x7poly * POWER(@x, 7.0);
        --Radians to Degrees
        SET @Longitude =  (@Lng_AsRad / @gbl_pi * 180.0)

        ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        SELECT @Latitude As Lat, @Longitude As Lng
    END
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this stored procedure?  I'm working a a similar stored procedure could use input

Comment: No, unfortunately. To enable our data to work better with web maps, we changed our spatial storage (whatever its called) in SQL Server to the SQL Server Geography format and are now using the WGS84 Coordinate system.  It was not a popular move at first but we're used to it now and its really easy to put our data on web maps now

Comment: Do you know how can I do that with any libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this but had to create a correction on the formula to create the closest approximation for my region.   I know there are better ways to handle the correction but it was close enough for my intended purpose.

This function is based on the NOAA Program SPCS83 (Vergsion 2.1)
http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/SPCS83/
Reference: http://www.softwright.com/faq/engineering/Coordinate%20Systems.html

Here is the Lat Function:

```
DECLARE @X numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @Y numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @t numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lon numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @x1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat0 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @part1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat numeric(15,8)

set @X =((@xCoord * .3048) - 500000)
set @Y =(@yCoord * .3048)
set @t = power(((Sqrt(power(@x,2) + Power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63),1.376682)
set @lon = ((ATAN(@X / (6184598.958 - @Y))) / 0.726384231) + -2.103121749
set @x1 = @X + 500000
set @lat0 = 1.570796326 - (2 * Atan(power( ((Sqrt(power(@x,2) + power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63) ,1.376682)))
set @part1 = (1 - (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0))) / (1 + (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0)))
set @lat1 = .570796326 - (2 * Atan(power(((Sqrt(Power(@x,2) + power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63),1.376682) * power(@part1, 0.041136)))

While Abs(@lat1 - @lat0) > 0.000000003
    Begin
         Set @lat0 = @lat1
         Set @part1 = (1 - (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0))) / (1 + (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0)))
         Set @lat1 = 1.570796326 - (2 * Atan( @t * ( power(@part1 ,(0.08227185422 / 2) ) ) ))   
    END

set @lat = @lat1 / 0.01745329252
set @lon = @lon / 0.01745329252

set @lat=(((@lat * 100000) / 100000) + .00331)
--set @lon =  @lon * 100000 
-- exec StatePlane2Geodetic 1084101.380000, 114080.430000

--print  cast(@lat as varchar(20)) + ', '    + cast(@lon as varchar(20))
return @lat
```

And here is the Lon Function:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @X numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @Y numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @t numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lon numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @x1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat0 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @part1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat1 numeric(15,8)
DECLARE @lat numeric(15,8)

set @X =((@xCoord * .3048) - 500000)
set @Y =(@yCoord * .3048)
set @t = power(((Sqrt(power(@x,2) + Power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63),1.376682)
set @lon = ((ATAN(@X / (6184598.958 - @Y))) / 0.726384231) + -2.103121749
set @x1 = @X + 500000
set @lat0 = 1.570796326 - (2 * Atan(power( ((Sqrt(power(@x,2) + power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63) ,1.376682)))
set @part1 = (1 - (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0))) / (1 + (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0)))
set @lat1 = .570796326 - (2 * Atan(power(((Sqrt(Power(@x,2) + power((6184598.958 - @y),2))) / 11760085.63),1.376682) * power(@part1, 0.041136)))

While Abs(@lat1 - @lat0) > 0.000000003
    Begin
         Set @lat0 = @lat1
         Set @part1 = (1 - (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0))) / (1 + (0.08227185422 * Sin(@lat0)))
         Set @lat1 = 1.570796326 - (2 * Atan( @t * ( power(@part1 ,(0.08227185422 / 2) ) ) ))   
    END

set @lat = @lat1 / 0.01745329252
set @lon = @lon / 0.01745329252

set @lat=(((@lat * 100000) / 100000) + .00331)
--set @lon =  @lon * 100000 


--print  cast(@lat as varchar(20)) + ', '    + cast(@lon as varchar(20))
return @lon
```